# Let $Y_{1},Y_{2},...,Y_{n}$ be a normal distribution where $\mu =2$ and $\sigma = 4$. Find $P(1.9 \leq \bar{Y}\leq 2.1) >= 0.99$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $Y_{1},Y_{2},...,Y_{n}$ be a random sample from a normal distribution where the mean is $2$ and the variance is $4$. How large must $n$ be in order that
$P(1.9 \leq \bar{Y}\leq 2.1) >= 0.99$.

Solution: Let $P(1.9 \leq \bar{Y}\leq 2.1) = P(\frac{1.9 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \leq \bar{Y}\leq \frac{2.1 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}) =   P(\frac{1.9 - 2}{2/\sqrt{n}} \leq Z\leq \frac{2.1 - 2}{2/\sqrt{n}}) >= 0.99  $ .

Then we look for a probability that is equal to about $0.99$ in the normal table.
Then $\frac{2.1 - 2}{2/\sqrt{n}} = 2.3$.

So solving for n we have $n = 2116$.

Can anyone please verify this?, I don't know if I  have to take in consideration $\frac{1.9 - 2}{2/\sqrt{n}}$, the other part of the inequality. In addition, there are so many approximations that are almost equal to 0.99. So I am not sure if $2.3$ works.

Any feedback/help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of Chebyshev's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality?

Comment: I still have not learn that. I am learning the normal distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a two-sided confidence interval $[1.9,2.1]$ with coverage probability $0.99$, the corresponding quantile is $0.995$, thus the correct $z$-score is $2.57583$, not $2.3$, and the desired $n$ satisfies $$\frac{2.1 - 2}{2/\sqrt{n}} = 2.57583.$$

Comment: so solving for n we get 2654. Thanks for the help.